# Fitting custom cumulative distribution

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, distribution, curve-fitting

I'm trying to create and adjust the following CDF:

```
nlDist /: CDF[nlDist[a_, b_, c_, d_], x_] :=(Exp[-a Exp[-x/b] - c Exp[-x/d]]);

FindDistributionParameters[{31, 46, 70, 87, 87, 93, 114, 128, 133,  134, 143, 155, 161, 161, 163, 177, 181, 207, 207, 226, 302, 315,319, 347, 347, 362, 375, 377, 413, 440, 447, 461, 464, 511, 524,556, 800, 860, 880, 954, 5200, 12000}, nlDist[a, b, c, d]]
```

But I get the that nlDist... is not a recognized distribution.

Somebody can modify my code to try to adjusting the CDF?
Thanks.

Comment: try usin ProbabilityDistribution to define your dist http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html.  go to mathematica.stackexchange.com if you cant make that go

Comment: It is just that I am doing with DIST = ProbabilityDistribution[
  Exp[-a Exp[-x/b] - c Exp[-x/d]], \[FormalX], 
  Assumptions -> Element[{a, b, c, d}, Reals]], but then I obtain the message: "The ProbabilityDistribution... is not a recongnized distribution, when applying FindDistributionParameters[{31,46...},DIST[a,b,c,d]].

Answer (score 0):

This "works" in  the sense of not throwing that error

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", 
        Exp[-a Exp[-x/b] - c Exp[-x/d]]}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
        Assumptions -> Element[{a, b, c, d}, Reals]]
 res = FindDistributionParameters[{31, 46, 70, 87, 87, 93, 114,
                                   128, 133, 134, 143, 155, 161, 161,
                                   163, 177, 181, 207, 207, 226, 302, 
                                   315, 319, 347, 347, 362, 375, 377,
                                   413, 440, 447, 461, 464, 511, 524,
                                   556, 800, 860, 880, 954, 5200, 12000}, dist]
```

Note that `ProbabilityDistribution` wants a *PDF* by default.

The resulting fit essentially fails. My intuition is you don't have enough data to meaningfully fit so many parameters.

Here is a working somewhat simpler  example:

a known distribution of data of the specified form:

```
 d0 = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", 
       Exp[- 3 Exp[-x/2]]}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
 data = RandomVariate[d0, 50];
```

a two parameter version of your form:

```
 dist = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", 
        Exp[-a Exp[-x/b]]}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
           Assumptions -> {Element[{a, b}, Reals]}];
```

find a fit, note giving starting values for the parameters helps a lot:

```
 res = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist , {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}]
```

the fit is close to what we put in (3,2):

> {a -> 2.70431, b -> 2.09066}

```
 Show[{
      ListPlot[ MapIndexed[ {# , First@#2/Length[data]} &, Sort@data ] ],
      Plot[ CDF[dist /. res]@x , {x, -2, 10} , PlotRange -> All]  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Great response George. It can help me. Then, I see that in AFINS 2.0 the initial values generates automatically. And I think that if Mathematica has a functino to do that, then the paramters can be passed to the fitted distribution as initial parameters. Do you know, or someboy knows if this is possible in Mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

May be that I have to pass some initial or start values. In fact, the program (AFINS 2.0) that I use to validate my results is found [here](http://lluvia.dihma.upv.es/ES/software/software.html). It first generates initial paameters ("Parametros iniciales" button), then one can adjust the final parameters values.

I would use that program but it can show the confidence or prediction bands. Also I would like to obtain the inverse function to get any quantile value, but I find some problems also.

Answer (score 0):

I encontered an important difference between AFINS 2.0 and the original function of TCEV of the article Two-Component Extrem Value Distribution, also implemented in the soft Extreme (Geostru):
This is the original:
Exp[-a Exp[-x/b] - c Exp[-x/d]]

But this is the one that fit well:

Exp[-a Exp[-x*b] - c Exp[-x*d]]

And this is better fitted by Mathematica if one uses ProbabilityDistribution in fact (at least visually).

I haven't explanation for this difference ¿?